# ASP changePassword Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, change-password

I am trying to customize a `<changePassword />` on C# and so I used this for testing:

```
ConfirmPasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Need confirmation password"
NewPasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Need new password"
PasswordRequiredErrorMessage="Need password"
```

The result is that I got asterisks to show the error message.
Is there a way to replace the asterisks and instead show the message like 'ChangePasswordFailureText' attribute.

I was thinking if it could be done with `<ChangePasswordTemplate\>` but I can't find any good tutorial for this purpose.

Comment: did you add it in .aspx page or code behind ?? try to put it in the aspx page <asp:ChangePassword NewPasswordRequiredErrorMessage="String" />

Answer (score 0):

For finer grain control of the form, I recommend using the ChangePasswordTemplate.  You can find a basic template in this stackoverflow post: [ChangePasswordTemplateExample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440545/asp-changepassword-control-customization)

If you need to work with the specific controls in code-behind you will want to use:

```
ChangePasswordControl.Controls[0].FindControl("MyControl")
```

Additionally, there are two events that are worthwhile, the onchangingpassword and onchangedpassword.  The ChangePassword works with the Membership provider and you have very little control on the page, but the onchangingpassword event can be used to force additional requirements on the password that the provider isn't checking (like making sure doesn't contain the name or email address).