# asp ChangePassword control in sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, change-password

I have a sublayout in sitecore that has nothing but a asp ChangePassword control.  This control has borders around it.  Looking at the developer tools I can see that there is a table added around this control.  I set RenderOuterTable = false on the ChangePassword control.  This doesn't seem to remove the table elements.

```
    <asp:ChangePassword ID="myChangePass" runat="server" RenderOuterTable="False">

    </asp:ChangePassword>
```

Any ideas what could be going wrong?

Comment: Never heard of that control before! Take a look at [this article](http://www.asp.net/cssadapters/membership/changepassword.aspx) and [this other stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440545/asp-changepassword-control-customization)

Answer (score 1):

I think the real key to this control is not so much in creating a presentation control that has the layout created for you, it's to provide you with access to the functionality while letting you style it yourself the same way you could style a wizard control or something. My experience with the .net based controls is that they're rather buggy and unreliable. Quite honestly, I wouldn't even use the .NET based change password control in Sitecore.  If you're set on it, I'd recommend styling it per the MSDN samples.

Also, some advice that I know this doesn't really answer your question exactly, but my suggestion is that if you're using Sitecore and you have WFFM installed, its so much easier to just drop a quick login form that can have all the validation and everything built in.